# SplitView-Based App: Display an independant view

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a splitview-based app, that has a popover menu containing 3 views.  I would like to add another view, that doesn't appear in the popover menu, and is displayed when a different button is clicked.

[image]
Here is a screenshot, with the popover menu, and the 'Log' button which I want to use to display my new view.

All of the other views are configured something like this:

```
 UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = nil;

    if (row == 0) {
        FirstDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[FirstDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstDetailView" bundle:nil];
        detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
    }

    ...

    NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController, detailViewController, nil];
    splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    [viewControllers release];
```

I tried to replicate this code for my new view:

```
-(void)displayLogView{


    UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = nil;

    LogDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[LogDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LogDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController = newDetailViewController;

    // Update the split view controller's view controllers array.
    NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController, detailViewController, nil];
    splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    [viewControllers release];

    [detailViewController release];
}
```

But nothing happens.  I think that I am missing the code to actually display the view.  I tried to find how the other views were displayed, but could not find anything (I got the code from the apple sample code).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a slide-over view try using `presentModalViewController` to show it and `dismissModalViewController` to get rid of it.

Comment: I just did some reading and this seems to be what I am looking for, thanks.